# Why can't an executable find a shared library only when run as a http request

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, exec

I have a php file that has a shell_exec call. The shell_exec functions runs a .sh file.

```
#!/bin/bash

filename=$(ls *.jpg -Art | tail -n 1)
codegen_dir=/usr/local/codegen/

cd "$codegen_dir"
out=$(./classifier /var/www/$filename)
echo $out
```

The executable 'classifier' exists in the codegen_dir and has 1 shared library dependency. The script runs correctly from the command line. The php file also runs correctly from the command line. however, when I run the php file as a http request I get the following in std_err:

"./classifier: error while loading shared libraries: libreader.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

The .so file is in the same directory as the executable

My php server root is : /var/www

- All files in the server root have the permissions:-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data
- All files in 'codegen_dir' have the permissions:  -rwxrwxrwx 1 ubuntu www-data
- I am able to read other files in the codegen_dir

Comment: Can we have the code of `./classifier` and in `httpd.conf`?

Comment: I haven’t made any changes to httpd.conf and I can’t share the code for the executable. However, I can clarify my question: it is an executable that has exactly one shared lib dependency(.so file), if that helps

Comment: The loader never checks the current directory for shared objects unless it is explicitly directed to via $LD_LIBRARY_PATH. See the ld.so(8) man page for more details. You can put your shared library in one of the standard places, see /etc/ld.so.conf. Example: /usr/local/lib/libreader.so

Comment: to reiterate: I am able to run the script on the command line, the issue is when I trigger it from a http request. Yes, I do have ld.so.conf set up

Answer (score 0):

Shared libarary path might be not accessible by apache user. You can allow classifier program in sudoers file for apache and use sudo to run classifier application as apache user

Or
 make shared libraray and its path accessible by all users by changing its permission

```
out=$(sudo ./classifier /var/www/$filename)
```

Try to login with apache user and run above script or try to access shared lib

```
su -s /bin/bash apache
```

Comment: As mentioned above, other files in the same directory as the shared library can be read by apache user

Comment: Try to login with apache user and run above script or try to access shared lib

Comment: I am able to run the script correctly as the apache user, but not as a http request. I think it is because the sub-process(fired from shell_exec) doesnt have access to LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Is there anyway to workaround this?

Comment: Try exporting  LD_LIBRARY_PATH at the top of shell script

Comment: exporting LD_LIBRARY_PATH at the top of shell script works, but is there a neater way to do this

Comment: Check for `/etc/apache2/envvars` file and put export command there and try